# DB2 - how to test if record exists before deleting

Tags: sql, db2

spent time trying to figure out how to construct a DB2 SQL statement that first checks if record exists before deleting it. looking for somewhere along the lines:

```
if exists(select 1 from my_table where my_table.my_field = current date) then
   delete from my_table where my_table.my_field = current date
```

TIA!

Comment: Why does it matter whether or not records are there?

Comment: Before executing it manually check it and then do delete operation .. u cant write conditions something like that

Comment: the stage that delete records crashes the datastage job with this error "No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE"

Comment: What is the reason for this? What do you think you will achieve with it?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, basically, i don't want to execute delete statement if there is nothing to delete. perhaps that will eliminate the error "No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE". this is the solution that i see without changing settings in db2 or datastage.

Comment: @user3753660 That message is from SQL0100W, which is a warning, not an error.  Not sure how you're executing the statement, but you should be able to differentiate between warnings and errors.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said this is a DataStage job, there are two ways you can handle this:

1) Add a message handler to convert that message from an error to a warning. See [this techdoc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418587).

2) (Maybe easier) Add a simple select around your delete statement to catch the number of rows deleted. DataStage won't complain about this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS DELETED
FROM OLD TABLE (
    DELETE FROM <your_table>
    WHERE <criteria>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are just concerned about the error code in the terminal with delete queries where no rows exists, then the query can be wrapped with begin atomic like this

```
BEGIN ATOMIC 
    DELETE FROM <TABLE> WHERE <CONDITION>'; 
END
```

When this executes this will not return an error code in the terminal.